# C strtok, split string to two part using first space

Tags: c, strtok

i have 3 pointers

```
char line[MAX_STR];
char *inputCmd,*inputArgs;
```

and i'm using

```
inputCmd = strtok(line," ");
```

I wonder how i can split it to just two parts
In example

```
line = {"COMMAND A PARAMTER TO CHECK..."};
```

I want the 
inputCmd will point to "COMMAND"
and inputArgs will point to "A PARAMTER TO CHECK..."

Thanks.
I

Comment: `inputCmd = line; if(inputArgs = strchr(line, ' ')) *inputArgs++ = 0;`. BTW `line` isn't pointer.

Comment: or `inputCmd = strtok(line," "); inputArgs = strtok(NULL, "\n");`

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to use the same token for every call to strok.

So if your format is

string1|space|remainder|nul|

you can call strtok with a space and the string, then call again with null for the string argument and nul for the token.